# What are the options to generate editors over existing rest api?

Tags: rest, user-interface, crud, scaffolding

I'm about to choose technology for some backoffice for existing site. Domain model is exposed over HTTP as REST-like API.

I wonder whether there is any technology which can provide customizable UI with CRUD operations.

It can be built over JS+HTML (preferable), but some other (silverlight or ...) also can be considered.

UPD: I thought of writing a Spinejs client application over that HTTP api, and spinejs  matches good with its concepts of models and collections accesible as GET, PUT, POST et c.

Maybe there is some scaffolding project to generate some foundation of such application?

Comment: Just a heads up that you are falling into a common trap http://www.jroller.com/rickard/entry/the_domain_model_as_rest